# c# core ef при выполнении хранимой процедуры не возвращаются значения в модель

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, stored-procedures

проект webapi на C#.

описана модель данных, которую возвращает хранимая процедура

```
public class Price
{
    public int GoodId { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Qnt { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

в контексте

```
public virtual DbSet<Price> Price { get; set; }
```

и описан ключ

```
builder.Entity<Price>().HasKey(x => new { x.GoodId, x.SupplierId, x.Code });
```

в контроллере выполняю хранимую процедуру

```
       var prices = _context.Price.FromSql($"EXECUTE [dbo].[GetPrice] @Code = '{Code}', @SupplierId = {SupplierId}, @GoodId = {GoodId}").ToList();

        if (prices == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return prices;
```

проблема в том что объект prices пустой, точнее он != null, но количество строк = 0. При этом сама хранимая процедура возвращает минимум одну строку. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
с другими хранимыми процедурами проблем нет. как заставить правильно возвращать значение ?

Comment: у вас проблема с хранимкой, но вы ни данные в БД, ни код хранимки не покажете?

Comment: @tym32167, с самой хранимой проблем нет, данные она возвращает, а если я их пытаюсь получить в контроллере сразу в объект, то объект получается пустой.

Comment: если бы вы всё показали, что я перечислил, кто то мог бы воспроизвести вашу проблему и поискать ошибку, а так вы просто ждете астрологов-телепатов. Ведь не зря же в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) написано про [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @tym32167, хранимка данные возвращает, [ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/WyahgvCQquR1WA)

Comment: в вопрос, добавляйте всё, что касается вопроса в вопрос, не надо никаких ссылок

Comment: @tym32167, добавил

Comment: я бы сначала поглядел через логи контекста или через sql profiler какой именно запрос идет на сервер из проги, возможно, в запросе что то не так или в параметрах.

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо за помощь, разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

спасибо за помощь, разобрался.
одинарные кавычки были лишними.
вот так все заработало:

```
var prices = _context.Price.FromSql($"EXECUTE [dbo].[GetPrice] @Code = {Code}, @SupplierId = {SupplierId}, @GoodId = {GoodId}").ToList();

    if (prices == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return prices;
```